# How to Export Performance Data in Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Is there a way to export performance data in Azure Application Insights?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, kind of. But not from there. You can use [Application Insights Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics) for that.

You have to create a query there that shows what you need. You can then export the results to csv or render it as a chart and save that one.

An example query to get you started could be:

```
requests 
| where timestamp >= ago(24h) 
| summarize percentiles(duration, 95), count()  by name
```

Queries are, once you get to know the language a bit, easy to write and you can get very interesting queries. Another performance example is

```
requests 
| where timestamp >= ago(24h) 
| summarize avg(duration), min(duration), max(duration), stdev(duration) , count()  by name 
| order by avg_duration  desc
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up opening up chrome dev tools, found the xhr that was pulling that data, then took the json response and did some string replace to create a csv out of it and imported in to sql server. Your way seems easier though.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to export the data to an sql server you can first configure application insights to do a continuous export to a blob and then with a Stream Analytics Job export this data in real time to the target you want, as for example an sql server, this last options also allows you powerful transformation of the data.